# Рисование кистью

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, mousepressevent, drawline

Мне нужна помощь в реализации кисти на *PyQt5*.

У меня уже есть некоторый код ивентов для мышки:

```
 ... 
 def mousePressEvent(self, event):
     if event.button() and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
         self.lastPoint = event.pos()
         self.scribbling = True

 def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
     if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribbling:
         self.drawLineTo(event.pos())

 def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
     if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.scribbling:
         self.drawLineTo(event.pos())
         self.scribbling = False
```

Внутри которых объявлена функция рисования кисти:

```
def drawLineTo(self, endPoint):
    painter = QPainter(self.image)
    painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth, Qt.SolidLine,
            Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
    painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, endPoint)
    self.modified = True

    rad = self.myPenWidth / 2 + 2
    self.update(QRect(self.lastPoint, endPoint).normalized().adjusted(-rad, -rad, +rad, +rad))
    self.lastPoint = QPoint(endPoint)
```

Но основная проблема в том, что из-за того, что эта функция объявлена в самих ивентах, то рисование идет сразу, а следовательно не получится добавить другие инструменты. 
Т.к. вместе с ними на постоянной основе будет рисоваться "карандаш", а мне нужно как-то от туда ее вытащить и присвоить соответствующей кнопке, чтобы оно включалось только по клику на эту кнопку.

---

Допустим у меня есть некоторый тулбар:

```
toolbar = self.addToolBar('Инструменты')
toolbar.addAction(self.pen)
```

Для которого есть свое действие:

```
self.pen = QAction(QIcon('Image/pen.png'), 'Карандаш', self)
self.pen.triggered.connect(self.      )
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в это действие присвоить функцию рисования и чтобы она работала лишь при нажатии на кнопку?

---

Может быть есть какие-нибудь бинды для этого, как в *tkinter*, на подобии:

```
def draw_pen(self):
    self.parent.config(cursor="arrow")
    self.parent.unbind("<Button-1>")
    self.parent.unbind("<Motion>")
    self.parent.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.button_press)
    self.parent.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_pencil_move)
    self.parent.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.draw_pencil_release)
```

И в итоге я просто присваивал кнопке эту функцию и все отлично работало.

Буду безмерно благодарен за ответы и особенно за примеры решения проблемы, либо примеры реализации кисти, которые не объявлены в ивентах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы практически все написали, осталось только привязать флаг `self.scribbling` 
к соответствующей кнопке, чтобы он включался только по клику на эту кнопку.

Видимо `self.scribbling` должен где-то выключаться. 
Реализуем включение и выключение флага `self.scribbling`, например, через действия тулбара.

Мне показалось, что метод `drawLineTo` излишний и был перенесен в `mouseMoveEvent`.
Пробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class MyScribbling(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.penOn = QAction(QIcon('Image/ok.png'), 'Включить рисование', self)
        self.penOn.triggered.connect(self.drawingOn)
        self.penOff = QAction(QIcon('Image/exit.png'), 'ВЫКЛЮЧИТЬ рисование', self)
        self.penOff.triggered.connect(self.drawingOff)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Инструменты')
        toolbar.addAction(self.penOn)
        toolbar.addAction(self.penOff)

        self.scribbling = False
        self.myPenColor = Qt.red      # +
        self.myPenWidth = 3           # +

        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.image     = QPixmap("Image/picture.png")
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.show()

    # +++ 
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # if event.button() and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:    # -
        if (event.button() == Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribbling:   # +
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            # self.scribbling = True                                # -

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.scribbling:

            # self.drawLineTo(event.pos())                          # -

            # +++
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth, 
                                Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            # self.modified = True                                  # ?
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

            # ?
            #rad = self.myPenWidth / 2 + 2
            #self.update(QRect(self.lastPoint, event.pos()).normalized().adjusted(-rad, -rad, +rad, +rad))
            #self.lastPoint = QPoint(event.pos())   

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.scribbling:
            #self.drawLineTo(event.pos())
            #self.scribbling = False  
            pass

#    Перенес в mouseMoveEvent
#    def drawLineTo(self, endPoint):
#        painter = QPainter(self.image)
#        painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
#        painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, endPoint)
#        self.modified = True  
#        rad = self.myPenWidth / 2 + 2
#        self.update(QRect(self.lastPoint, endPoint).normalized().adjusted(-rad, -rad, +rad, +rad))
#        self.lastPoint = QPoint(endPoint)        

    # +++    
    def drawingOn(self):
        self.scribbling = True

    # +++    
    def drawingOff(self):
        self.scribbling = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainMenu = MyScribbling()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]