# PyQt. QPainter. paintEvent

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Я хочу чтобы при при перемещении мыши, в окне проводилась линия на том месте, где был проведён указатель мыши. Для этого я использовал `mouseMoveEvent`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.pen.setColor(Qt.green)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        self.qp = QPainter(self)
        self.qp.setPen(self.pen)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        r = event.pos()
        self.qp.drawPoint(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Следующий код выдаёт ошибку:

```
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
```

Как исправить?

Comment: на самом деле постов на эту тему уже опубликовано много, вот например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968480/pyqt5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/968522#968522 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884093/%d0%a0%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e/884134#884134

Comment: но мне нравится https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005630/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1005651#1005651 попробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я добавил в комментарии пояснения:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pen = QPen()
        self.pen.setColor(Qt.green)
        self.pen.setWidth(20)  # Больше размер, чтобы точка была заметна

        self.pos_points = []         # Переменная для рисования точек
        self.setMouseTracking(True)  # Флаг, чтобы mouseMoveEvent срабатывал без нажатия мышки

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        if not self.pos_points:  # Рисуем если есть данные для этого
            return

        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setPen(self.pen)

        # Рисование на виджете лучше делать в paintEvent
        for pos in self.pos_points:
            p.drawPoint(pos)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.pos_points.append(event.pos())  # Сохранение данных для рисования
        self.update()                        # Вызов события перерисовки виджета


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**PS.**

[Если любопытно, то есть более полный пример рисования с несколькими точками разом, да и событий обработки больше](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8ba59f942ed6a939cc3626b536cae483c682bbac/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5_paintEvent_example.py#L49)

Comment: Появляется кисть в виде зелёного прямоугольника, который следует за мышью, но ничего не рисует(линия не появляется).

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков, потому что paintEvent на каждом вызове рисует на чистом холсте. Нужно сохранять в список и рисовать уже список. Либо, рисовать на `QImage` в `mouseMoveEvent`, а в `paintEvent` рисовать ту картинку. Пример первого накидал

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков, кст, для большего контроля можно переопределить `mousePressEvent` и `mouseReleaseEvent`, чтобы рисование было только при нажатой кнопке мышки. В конструкторе создаете флаг, пусть будет `self.is_press = False`, в `mousePressEvent` его ставите в `True`, в `mouseReleaseEvent` как `False`, а в `mouseMoveEvent` проверяете что флаг `True` и только тогда сохраняете позицию и вызываете перерисование

Comment: А когда вызывается ```paintEvent```? Или я сам могу его вызывать в программе когда нужно?

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков, нужно искать, конкретно не помню, например при показе виджета, при изменении размера окна, по-моему, еще когда другое окно перекрывает ваше. Ну и можете сами вызывать событие перерисования через `update()` и `repaint()`, читайте официальную документацию там про это есть: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent